# InnerHTML property of DOM element changed, but not rendering

Tags: javascript, html, dom, innerhtml

so I'm using innerHTML to try to add a dom element with a count variable, I'm console.logging the dom element and the property innerHTML changed to what I want, but it's not rendering to the page/ adding the dom element..

console.log on dom element
    `[a.aero, innerHTML: "<span>4</span>"]`

code to change dom
    `document.getElementsByClassName("aero").innerHTML="<span>"+count+"</span>";`

inspect element on targeted class element
  `<a class="aero" href="/c/">
    <script src="js/aero.js"></script>
  </a>`

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

getElementsByClassName returns a list (even if it's only 1) of elements - so your code is **NOT** actually changing the innerHTML of any DOM element at all

so you could use something like

```
document.getElementsByClassName("aero")[0].innerHTML="<span>"+count+"</span>";
```

if you know there will only ever be one element with "aero" class

Comment: oh my god, thank you so much @Jaromanda X.. honestly, thank you man.

Answer (score 1):

> The getElementsByClassName() method returns a collection of an element's child elements with the specified class name, as a NodeList object.

You need to do this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("aero")[0].innerHTML="<span>"+count+"</span>";
```

Refer [getElementsByClassName() - W3](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getelementsbyclassname.asp)